# count down timer with days, months, years

Tags: java, html, countdown, clock

I've been driving myself crazy for the past few days about how to write the coding using Java and (I also have to use the Math.Floor function) for converting milliseconds into days, months and years. I'm trying to create a countdown clock from current time to the 2020 Tokyo Olympics.

I see an abundance of information regarding seconds, minutes, hours and days but that's not the variables I'm looking for. I'm new to writing code so apologies in advance if I'm not explaining this well! The milliseconds I'm trying to convert is 42640670041, and this is all I've managed to work out:

var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you want to convert the milliseconds to months and years or you want to know how many years, months, days, ... seconds until the Tokyo Olympics?

Comment: Are you using java 8?  If so, you've got `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(...);`.

Comment: Okay so the end result I'm looking for is to have a countdown timer in years, months and days pop up as an alert in my browser. Logically I know I have to calculate the time between the dates, and I've done that with 

var countDownDate = new Date("24 July, 2020 00:00:00").getTime();
var now = new Date().getTime();
var distance = countDownDate - now;

but basically when I do that, my alert pops up as an error, because there aren't any calculations involved I think (eg. 1000*60*60 etc.) and those are the calculations I can't figure out.